# SurfaceView move/zoom out view

Tags: android, zooming, surfaceview, move, pan

I have problem with SurfaceView, have objects on screen, can move/pan and pinch zoom
Problem is with size, I don't wanna move objects from screen (picture show some)
http://i58.tinypic.com/2387bq.jpg

I have setup fixed size of layout in surfaceCreated method

```
LayoutParams lp = this.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = 2000; // required width
lp.height = 2000; // required height
this.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

but don't know how to restrict content to be inside view (even on zoom), any help is appreciated

Comment: you should probably consider TextureView instead of SurfaceView as it is better suited for any transformations: *"Unlike SurfaceView, TextureView does not create a separate window but behaves as a regular View. This key difference allows a TextureView to be moved, transformed, animated, etc."*

Comment: And how I can limit TextureView bounds so can't drag outside screen view???

Comment: just set left-top view position so that it is always visible

Comment: see `updatePosition()` method here: http://pastebin.com/DC2Zmz8P

Comment: did not, switched to Drawable (cause have same drawing method on canvas)